# MS Reporting services - How to pass cell color

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report that has some data values. Each data value can be of a 'good' or 'bad' quality. I would like to pass a value color through the dataset using a custom C# data provider object. 
Once in the report designer, I can use '**Fields!MyColumn.Value**' and it works fine. There is also an option to type '**Fields!MyColumn.Color**', but I don't know how to initialize it. Please help.

This is a code fragment I use to load some data to the report:

```
IDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
  dataset.Tables["dtTable"].Load(dataReader);
  dataReader.Close();

  //provide local report information to viewer
  reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource =
       "Client.Reports.Reports.Sample.rdlc";

  //prepare report data sources
  ReportDataSource dsTable = new ReportDataSource();
  dsTable.Name = "dtTableData";
  dsTable.Value = dataset.Tables["dtTable"];
  reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dsTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with the situation but it seems that if it takes a string you should be able to pass anything that the Color field in the report usually takes.  Any string like "#ffffff" or "white" or an expression like '=IIF(Fields!MyColumn.Value = 1, "blue", "red")'.  It if requires an integer, then you should set it according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145991.aspx

Comment: I can pass color values, this is not a problem. Maybe the question title is not 100% accurate. I can create a new column in the dataset and set the value to "red" or "blue". This is the workaround I use right now. This way I have to type **Fields!MyColorColumn.Value** to get to my color. Instead, I want to have one multi-dimensional column and type **Fields!MyColumn.Value** for values and **Fields!MyColumn.Color** for colors. The color, like the value is required for each cell.